# How to move past undeserializable messages in Spring Kafka 1.3 with Avro

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, avro, spring-kafka

I can't upgrade to Spring 5 so I'm stuck with spring-kafka 1.3 and its limited error handling.  So I have no access to ConsumerAwareErrorHandler or SeekToCurrent error handlers from spring-kafka 2.

I'm using a `@KafkaListener`-annotated method to listen to a topic, I've configured the `io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer` as my value deserializer.

The problem is if I end up with a message in my topic that is not in Avro format the KafkaMessageListenerContainer poll loop gets stuck.  The deserializer throws an exception on the message and the poll loop never seeks past it so the next time through the loop it tries deserializing the same message and keeps looping, dumping the same error thousands of time per second into my log.

There doesn't seem to be a way to get a NeverRetryPolicy or anything in edge-wise, but I can `factory.getContainerProperties().setErrorHandler()`.  Unfortunately I'm not sure what I can do from there.

Is there something I can Autowire into my error handler that I can use to seek forward 1 offset on error?  Not sure what that is, the docs don't talk much about what you can actually DO with the ErrorHandler and most examples I can find are for spring-kafka 2.X.  Like, it won't deserialize, there's NOTHING I can do with the message, it will NEVER work, I want to avoid retrying it ever again and it seems most Stackoverflow questions are about doing the opposite.

I've also seen some folks just wrap the Deserializer from Avro with their own class that eats the exception and returns null.  Is that a better plan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the deserialization fails well before Spring gets the data - the problem is in Kafka itself.

In 2.2, we added the `ErrorHandlingDeserializer2` which wraps the real deserializer and sends a signal to the listener container so the error can be sent to the error handler.

In older versions, you would need to write your own deserializer wrapper - however, there is no code in the container to deal with the situation so your catch block would need to return a real Object that is a signal to your listener that the deserialization failed.

Let's say your listener receives `Invoice`. Your catch block could create a subclass, say `BadInvoice` which you can then detect in your listener and discard it.

> I've also seen some folks just wrap the Deserializer from Avro with their own class that eats the exception and returns null. Is that a better plan?

You can return `null` if you never get real null records, but you would have to add `@Payload(required = false)` to the method parameter.

Comment: Question though:  Yes the deserialization fails inside kafka and really messes up the polling loop so it never gets to the listener but I DO get the SerializationException in the ErrorHandler method, is there a possibility of accessing SOMETHING to seek there?  I've tried implementing ConsumerSeekAware but my ThreadLocal<ConsumerSeekCallback>.get() is null when the ErrorHandler tries to get to it...IIRC even when one is registered before the error but I'll check again in the AM.

Comment: Yes, it is true that we call the error handler for general exceptions (in addition to those thrown by the listener). However, Kafka provides us with no information about which topic/partition/offset failed to deserialize. Even if it did, it's hard to see what we can do. The `poll()` will return multiple records (up to 500 by default). Even if there is only one topic/partition, there is nothing the error handler can do since we can't skip the bad record without losing earlier good records. Unfortunately, the only solution is a "smart" deserializer (or reset the offset with a command line tool).

Comment: Ah,  `this.containerProperties.getGenericErrorHandler().handle(var11, (Object)null);`  Well...dang.

Comment: Actually...Sorry to keep hammering on this but the Avro Serializers actually include topic, partition, and offset of the failed message in the error message...I'd need regex to parse them out but assuming I could, would I be able to seek to 1 past that or do I still run into the batch problem?

Comment: You still run into the batch problem, unless you set `max.poll.records` to 1 (which will hurt performance).